Handle async packages in Python Tasks inside of Airflow
I'm dealing with an annoying error on my local Airflow setup.
I use a LocalExecutor, with a MySQL database (if that helps).
My task looks something like that:

@task()
def pdf_to_text_task() -> None:
    file_storage_instance = get_file_storage_instance_from_task()

    pdf_fpath = get_pdf_fpath(file_storage_instance)
    pages = parse_pdf(pdf_fpath) # <--- this package breaks Airflow task

    pages = re.split(r"(?<!\|)---(?! \|)", pages[0])

    text = pdf_to_text(pages)
    filename = pdf_fpath.name.split(".")[0]
    save_file(json.dumps(text), f"{filename}.json")

And when using this package, I get this error:
[2024-04-24, 20:20:17 CEST] {task_context_logger.py:104} ERROR - Executor reports task instance <TaskInstance: main.pdf_to_text_task 6f30866d-72b3-449b-8e74-7d4a4b99aaa1 [queued]> finished (failed) although the task says it's queued. (Info: None) Was the task killed externally?

According to the documentation of the package behind parse_pdf, it's an async first package. (It simply consists of a package that calls an API).
I'm very frustrated because there is no real root cause that could be causing this.
I'm only assuming that the aforementioned package is causing this issue because it's the only change.
What could be causing this error?
Thanks!

If I get you correct you try to run is async function (coroutine) as regular function, this won't work you and you need to run it in asyncio event loop by use asyncio.run
import asyncio

@task()
def pdf_to_text_task() -> None:
    ...
    pages = asyncio.run(parse_pdf(pdf_fpath))


